# How can I iterate over a stack of maps: std::stack< std::map<string, string> >?

Tags: c++, stack

I have a for-loop that iterates over the stack of maps, but when I execute the code i get a segmentation fault. My code is this:

```
// std::stack< std::map<string, string> > STACK;
size_t getStackSize() { return this->STACK.size();}
std::stack< std::map<string, string> > getSTACK() { return this->STACK;}
for (size_t i = 0; i < ObjSTACK.getStackSize(); ++i )
{
    for (auto& [v, l] : ObjSTACK.getSTACK().top())
    {
        std::cout << v << ':' << l << '\n';
    }    
    ObjSTACK.getSTACK().pop();
}
```

Why am I getting the segmentation fault? Are there better ways to iterate over a std::stack< std::map<string, string> > ?

Comment: `ObjSTACK.getStackSize()`? This means `ObjSTACK` is something else then`std::stack`, please provide [mcve]. Also it is sure that `getStackSize()` lies.

Comment: The normal approach is `while (!stack.empty()) { /* use top() item */; stack.pop(); }` -- given your weird for-loop using some unknown "size" value, my guess is that you're still looping after the stack is empty, and the `top()` access throws.

Comment: `while (!ObjSTACK.getSTACK().empty())`

Comment: @MarekR My function getSize() returns the value of the functions std::stack< std::map<string, string> > STACK.size() which is from the STL lib.

Comment: Ok that `getSize` returns that, but you used `getStackSize` - messy code? Focuses on [mcve].

Comment: @KriptaStudios instead complaining, put more afford to ask question properly. Here is basic instruction: [ask]. Apparently you are beginner, if you fail to provide [mcve] just paste everything you have.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`getStack()` is returning a *copy* of the `std::stack` each time it is called, thus

```cpp
while (!ObjSTACK.getSTACK().empty())
```

would be very inefficient at best, but

```cpp
ObjSTACK.getSTACK().pop();
```

would be a no-op, since you are popping from a temp `std::stack`, not the original.  Thus `getStackSize()` would not change value, and the outer loop would run forever.

Make `getStack()` return a reference instead, so that the loop can actually modify the `std::stack`:

```cpp
std::stack< std::map<string, string> >& getSTACK() { return this->STACK; }
```